# Ubuntu virtual machine shows black screen before login

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have recently started fiddling with virtual machines. I have set up one with Ubuntu 64bit and it unexpectedly stopped working. I used VirtualBox to create it.

I can no longer turn it on as I encounter a black screen after the Ubuntu logo with the loader are shown. Firstly, I encountered an error, namely `failed to send host log message`, so I changed the graphics controller from VMSVGA to VBoxVGA and the error stopped being logged to the screen. However, I still can't turn my system on.

I tried increasing the video memory and turning the system on in various ways, such as headless, and the others available, but they didn't change anything. Additionally, I turned off and on my computer, as well as the VM (even with the `ACPI` option). How could I fix this, so that I can turn on my virtual machine again?